# Execute a command if a player is standing in a certain CHUNK - Minecraft Java 1.19.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a Minecraft game that is similar to the game polytopia, but I am having trouble with the "exploring" feature. The exploring feature basically allows the player to walk around their 1 chunk spawning area, and there is a glass 1 thick floor around the floating chunk, the player can step on the glass, on either side of the chunk. *Basically I want to run something like this: execute if entity @a[chunk=[62,-2]*. I was thinking about this way because when you forceload a chunk, it forceloads as a 2 number area, like [62, -2], so I want a way to see if the player is inside that chunk. For testing, you can just *run say test* I created something similar to this but it is very inefficient, I just did, if a player is standing on a certain color glass, it will run the command. **I would prefer in game commands inside command blocks rather than datapacks**.

Here is the inefficient way I did it: (video)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tUKIl7kEpjeLV9no-vDg5VIvPAVFTNJg/view?usp=share_link

I did notice something in MCStacker with a "SpawnForced" Option, and I'm thinking that *could* be helpful

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: Minecraft Java 1.19.4. I'll edit my question quick. Sorry for not making that specific!

Answer (score 3):

I stored my x position and my z position as a scoreboard "x", and "z", then I duplicated that scoreboard by setting it to "storeX" and "storeZ", so I can still use "x" and "z" scoreboards, without changing their values in an operation. I created the scoreboard objectives:

```
/scoreboard objectives add z dummy
/scoreboard objectives add x dummy
/scoreboard objectives add storeZ dummy
/scoreboard objectives add storeX dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Positions dummy
/scoreboard objectives add ChunkZ dummy
/scoreboard objectives add ChunkX dummy
/scoreboard objectives add 16 dummy
/scoreboard players set @a 16 16
```

Then I ran the commands in a datapack (If somebody wanted to do this without a datapack, just make the scoreboards with the lines above, and put each of these lines below into separate repeating command blocks (except for #comments)):

```
execute store result score @a z run data get entity @a[limit=1] Pos[2]
execute store result score @a x run data get entity @a[limit=1] Pos[0]
scoreboard players operation @a storeZ = @a z
scoreboard players operation @a storeX = @a x

execute store result score @a ChunkX run scoreboard players operation @a storeX /= @a 16
execute store result score @a ChunkZ run scoreboard players operation @a storeZ /= @a 16



#STORE POSITIONS ON SIDEBAR: OPTIONAL
scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Positions

scoreboard players operation X Positions = JKWarrior15 x
scoreboard players operation Z Positions = JKWarrior15 z
scoreboard players operation ChunkX Positions = JKWarrior15 ChunkX
scoreboard players operation ChunkZ Positions = JKWarrior15 ChunkZ
#--------------------------------------------
```

After that, I created an execute if function, where I would run:

```
/execute if score JKWarrior15 ChunkX matches 62 if score JKWarrior15 ChunkZ matches -2 run say You are in chunk [62,-2]!
```

and it worked!

Answer (score -2):

to check if a player is standing within a specific chunk, you can use the /execute positioned command with the if entity sub-command to check for players within a specific area. Here's an example command you can try:

```
/execute positioned 62 0 -2 if entity @a[x=62,y=0,z=-2,dx=15,dy=255,dz=15]
```

This command checks if there are any players within the chunk at coordinates (62, -2) by using the positioned sub-command to set the command's execution position to the center of the chunk. The if entity sub-command then checks for players within a box of size 16x256x16 (the size of a single chunk) centered at the execution position.

If you want to run a specific command when a player is detected within the chunk, you can add the command to the end of the /execute command, like this:

```
/execute positioned 62 0 -2 if entity @a[x=62,y=0,z=-2,dx=15,dy=255,dz=15] run say You are in the chunk!
```

This will make the command block display a message in the chat whenever a player is detected within the chunk.

Regarding the "SpawnForced" option in MCStacker, this is used to forcibly load a chunk into memory regardless of the player's proximity to it. This can be useful for maintaining a certain area, but it's not necessary for your current use case of detecting when a player is within a specific chunk.

Comment: except OP asked for **Chunk** [62 -2] not **position** 62 -2.